# Translator component with twig trans

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to have my twig templates translated using the Symfony Translator Component and .mo files. I used the i18n extention before but wanted a more reliable approach since locale handling for translations on Windows is a nightmare.

These class functions prepare the translation and template:

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param string $template_dir 
 * @param string $locale
 * @param string $locale_path
 */
public function __construct($template_dir, $locale, $locale_path)
{

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($template_dir);
    $this->parser = new TemplateNameParser();
    $this->template = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
    $this->translator = new Translator($locale);
    $this->translator->addLoader('mo', new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\MoFileLoader());
    $this->translator->addResource('mo', $locale_path, $locale);
    $this->template->addExtension(new TranslationExtension($this->translator));

}
/**
 * Render template.
 */
public function render($name,$parameters=[]) {
    return $this->template->loadTemplate($name,$parameters)->render();
}
```

Then i have this template:

```
<h1>{% trans 'Hello World!' %}</h1>
```

which throws this error:

> Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected token. Twig was looking for the
>   "with", "from", or "into" keyword.

Which i get because i am not adding the Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n extension to twig environment. If i do that, the texts in trans functions are not translated because i am not using the filter as i should. For it to work i need to use the trans filter like so: `{{ 'Some text'|trans }}`.

Is there a way to make translation work with `{% trans 'Some text' %}` instead of `{{ 'Some text'|trans }}`? For example, can i add a custom trans function somewhere in the chain?

**Note:** I know that `{% trans %}Some text{% endtrans %}` works, but all my templates already use this syntax `{% trans 'Some text' %}`, and i would like to prevent having to rewrite everything.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but shouldn't it be `{% trans('Hello World!') %}` if it's a function?

Comment: No. That is the way the twig trans function works `{% trans 'Some text' %}`.

Comment: The [Symfony Translations Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.htm) seems to mention the syntax: `{% trans %}'Some text'{% endtrans %}`, would that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes `{% trans %}Some text{% endtrans %}` works. But i will have to alter all 200 templates to use that syntax. I would like to prevent that. I will add a comment to my question to include this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specific combination of tools: Do you have any pointers to the documentation of the `{% trans 'lalal translate this' %}` syntax? Is this an older syntax, or from a different extension?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to stem from incompatible twig and symfony translator versions. But i am not sure tbh.

In my case, i solved the problem long-term by writing a simple script to replace the incorrect syntax with the correct one in each template file.

```
foreach (glob("your_template_path/*/*/*.twig") as $filename) {

    $content = file_get_contents($filename);

    $content = preg_replace_callback('/{% trans "[\s\S]+?" %}/',function($matches) {
        $text = str_replace(['{% trans','%}','"'],'',$matches[0]);
        return '{% trans %}'.trim($text).'{% endtrans %}';
    },$content);
    $content = preg_replace_callback('/{% trans \'[\s\S]+?\' %}/',function($matches) {
        $text = str_replace(['{% trans','%}',"'"],'',$matches[0]);
        return '{% trans %}'.trim($text).'{% endtrans %}';
    },$content);

    file_put_contents($filename,$content);

}
```

Maybe that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

## "{% trans  %}Hello World{% endtrans %}!"